# How can I use "dispatchTouchEvent" in a Service Class to the current Activity?

Tags: java, android, service, touch

what I want it's when I receive a callback in my service with data, emulate a touchEvent in the current screen that is running.

Comment: How can I use “dispatchTouchEvent” in a Service Class to the **current Activity**? I want to use dispatchTouchEvent in my service **without having any activity** inside this. - those two statements are mutually exclusive, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain well. I have a service where I do some stuff and when I receive a callback with data, I want to make emulate a touch event in the current screen running.

Comment: so use [bound local service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder) pattern

Comment: and of course you can inject the touch events to your activities only